# Binding a class to a view/viewgroup in Android?

Tags: android, viewgroup

In Android I have a class contains 2 properties. I've created many objects from it and put them into an ArrayList, then using ArrayAdapter to bind the List to a TableView as you see. Once the list is changed, the view will be updated.

The question is, how can I bind my properties with these 2 TextViews in a table-row (a so-called ViewGroup in Android)...? I've tried to take data from the list into 2 String-array: dates and values, but that's odd...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the `getView()` method of your adapter, use [setTag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29), passing in the object you want to attach. You can then, for example, retrieve the object in `onListItemClick()` (assuming you're using a ListView) by calling `Log logItem = (Log) view.getTag()`.

Comment: Thank you Aert ^^.
I'm quite new to Android... I'll try it and feedback later.